# Lock a Service-Bus Queue and prevent others from accessing it

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, microservices

I have multiple queues that multiple clients insert messages into them.

On the server side, I have multiple micro-services that access the queues and handle those messages. I want to lock a queue whenever a service is working on it, so that other services won't be able to work on that queue.

Meaning that if service A is processing a message from queue X, no other service can process a message from that queue, until service A has finished processing the message. Other services can process messages from any queue other than X.

Does anyone has an idea on how to lock a queue and prevent others from accessing it? preferably the other services will receive an exception or something so that they'll try again on a different queue.

**UPDATE**

Another way can be to assign the queues to the services, and whenever a service is working on a queue no other service should be assigned to the queue, until the work item was processed. This is also something that isn't easy to achieve.

Comment: This is against the spirit of message queueing. Messages are supposed to be independent. Not saying you shouldn't do this but it's a risky approach.

Comment: @usr Do you have a different architectonic solution for my problem?

Comment: You could use a SQL database as a queue. Queue tables are a well known pattern. Databases handle locking quite flexibly.

Comment: Why would you need to 'lock the queue'? Each message is a unit of work, and you take a 'lock' on that message. There really is not a single reason to lock the whole queue, that's not how it works.

Comment: @LeonCullens There's an issue of order in which those work items should be processed. Because I'm using multiple services, I don't won't a situation to occur that two services took work items A_1 and A_2 from queue A before A_1 was processed. If A_1 was taken by a service, then no other service should be able to pop A_2 until A_1 was finished. The other services can pop B_1 or C_1 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use Azure's redis to store the locks in-memory and have micro-services that manage those locks using the redis store.

The `lock()` and `unlock()` operations are atomic and the lock has a TTL, so that a queue won't be locked indefinitely.

Comment: Apparently changing the queue status invalidates the lock on the message and causes errors...

Comment: Repeating my comment here to warn future visitors: If the consumer dies after disabling the queue it becomes permanently unavailable. This is very fragile. It's also working against the way the system was designed which is a more risky approach.

Comment: Also, this should not work. 2 consumers might pull a message at the same time.

Comment: Eventually, I'm using a azure redis to store the locks in-memory and I have micro-services that manage those locks with the redis.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Frankly, this is what my answer says... Regarding Redis, I see the risk that the lock might not be released if your code fails. So make sure to add a timeout in some form.

Comment: In redis you can set a timeout to a value that you store. That way, I can also set a timeout to the lock. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are several built-in ways of doing this.  If you only have a single worker, you can set `MessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1`.

If you have multiple, you can use the [Singleton](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton) attribute.  This gives you the option of setting it in Listener mode or Function mode.  The former gives the behavior you're asking for, a serially-processed FIFO queue.  The latter lets you lock more granularly, so you can specifically lock around critical sections, ensuring consistency while allowing greater throughput, but doesn't necessarily preserve *order*.

*My Guess* is they'd have implemented the singleton attribute similarly to your Redis approach, so performance should be equivalent.  I've done no testing with that though.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using [Azure Service Bus message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions)

All messages in your queue must be tagged with the same `SessionId`. In that case, when a client receives a message, it locks not only this message but all messages with the same `SessionId` (effectively whole queue).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus is a broker with competing consumers. You can't have what you're asking with a general queue all instances of your service are using.

Comment: Do you have a any suggestions on how to Implement what I asked?

Comment: Are you trying to "lock" the queue or the message?

Comment: I don't want two services to pop from `Queue X` at the same time... If `Service A` pops from `Queue X`, only after `Service A` finished working on the work item, `Service B` will be able to pop from `Queue X`. I updated the question with what I finally did.

Answer (score 0):

Put the work items into a relational database. You can still use queues to push work to workers but the queue items can now be empty. When a worker receives an item he know to look into the database instead. The content of the message is disregarded.

That way messages are independent and idempotent. For queueing to work these two properties usually must hold.

That way you can more easily sequence actions that actually are sequential. You can use transactions as well.

Maybe you don't need queues at all. Maybe it is enough to have a fixed number of workers polling the database for work. This loses auto-scaling with queues, though.

Comment: My main problem is that if service A is processing a message from queue X, no other service can process a message from that queue, until service A has finished processing the message.

How does this help me with my issue?

Comment: You can do this kind of locking through the database. For example, insert a row that says "service a is running right now". And other consumers will see that row (or block on it) and not process. You can't do that with queues alone. Can't lock a queue.

Comment: Actually, I found this feature: `queueDesc.Status = EntityStatus.ReceiveDisabled;` for queue's `QueueDescription` object. This feature changes the state of the queue. You can disable receive, send, or both, and then enable it again.

Comment: If the consumer dies after disabling the queue it becomes permanently unavailable. This is very fragile.

Comment: Here's another idea: Use queueing like you normally would but use a single-row table in a SQL database as a lock. The code would something like `BeginTran(); WriteToRow(); ProcessMessage(); Rollback();`. You could use `LOCK_TIMEOUT` or, better, `READPAST` as well.

Comment: I prefer handling the situations of unavailable queues rather than moving to SQL and losing scalability.

Comment: @shlatchz what scalability are you talking about? You are serializing execution. This does not scale at all by principle. You can still make use of the buffering nature of queues.